# How to Specify Interbase Service Name with TIBRestore

Tags: interbase

Per the Interbase Operations Guide, GBAK allows the IB server location to be specified like this:

-se localhost:service_mgr

Or if we were remoting to a server named "test" we could specify:

-se test:service_mgr

This would restore the data local to server "Test", or in the former example it would restore on the machine you're running the restore on which would give better performance.

How can this be specified in TIBRestore? There is a protocol property with TCP or Local. Does specifying the local protocol use localhost service_mgr? Or is it controlled by passing localhost as the server name?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a server named "jupiter" restoring to a server named "pluto" over a TCP/IP connection:

```
gbak -r user -joe -pass blurf@ -se jupiter:service_mgr /backup/foo.ibk pluto:/companydb/foo.ib
```

From what I recall, you can also use a TCP/IP address, instead of the destination server name (i.e., `10.20.30.254` instead of `pluto`). That part is not really stated as such in the documentation but works on TCP/IP.

See [the official examples](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/2020/en/Some_backup_and_restore_examples) for examples.